# Firefox add-on to indicate in which profile I'm currently on

Tags: firefox

I'm using multi-profiles via `about:profiles`, however it's difficult to recognise which window belongs to which user profile.

So I'm looking for Firefox add-on which will give me some clear indication on which user profile I'm currently on, by either showing the name of it (similar as in Chrome, in the top-right corner), or by at least by changing the Firefox's app icon.

Comment: Why don't you use a profile manager addon?

Comment: @onurcano22 Can you post the link to that add-on? As I'm not clear, as I'm already using [Profile Manager](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles) which is built-in functionality.

Comment: Sorry, I guessed there should be some profile manager addons in Firefox site however I couldn't find something compatible with the newest version of Firefox. If you want one for the 2016 version of Firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/profileswitcher/?src=search and use this addon only if you trust it.

Answer (score 2):

A quick google search for "firefox profile indicator" resulted in a number of links. A couple links told me that the add-on no longer works with my version of Firefox. Yeah, no worries.

One of the more promising links, a github resource, also contained a reference that the system was no longer an optimum solution and was replaced with "containers."

Chasing that lead resulted in a promising [add-on for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multi-account-containers/).

From the linked site:

> Firefox Multi-Account Containers lets you keep parts of your online
>   life separated into color-coded tabs that preserve your privacy.
>   Cookies are separated by container, allowing you to use the web with
>   multiple identities or accounts simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

As settings are supposedly per profile, just choose **different themes** for each profile.